# How to get only targeted value in text file

Tags: c, parsing, text

> 2.01; 0.441726296835717; -0.564010125045376; -0.416244141468842; -0.559920773166141; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;
>
> 2.025; 0.441775420652974; -0.563994918440088; -0.416232918868251; -0.55990567681625; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;
>
> 2.04; 0.441888754828675; -0.563983772823187; -0.416224693310709; -0.55983357975964; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;
>
> 2.055; 0.441968179548186; -0.563946209146259; -0.416242015187121; -0.559795843365589; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;
>
> 2.07; 0.442017290067744; -0.563930996016906; -0.416230786556594; -0.55978074219736; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;

Texts above are the data I've been struggle with. Those are 5 sentences(far more actually), consist of 21 numbers and it is separated by semicolon(;). I only want to extract 4 numbers from 2nd to 5th number which are shown in long numbers.

I've tried parsing but each segmented numbers have to be assigned to different variables so that I can add some calculation process. I really hope I can get some tips even if it's broad. The language used is C.

Comment: Could you highlight which numbers you're trying to get? And what language are you using to try and parse it?

Comment: iterate through the file line by line, splitting each line on ';', and then extract the elements at the appropriate indices. Depending on the language, doing so ranges from the utterly trivial (e.g. Python) to the mildly annoying (e.g. C) with most modern languages being closer to Python than C when it comes to such a basic task. It is pointless to say more unless you say more about what you are trying to do and what language you are trying to use to do so.

Comment: @SLC Thank you for kind reply. 0.441726296835717; -0.564010125045376; -0.416244141468842; -0.559920773166141; These long digits are my target for the first sentence and also same for other sentences. I am using C to parse it. Maybe I don't have an idea with setting data type and dealing with semicolon(;). Even a short comment could be a great inspiration to me :)

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you very much. I was totally out of sense to tell you that I am using C programming. Like you said, I looks basic but annoying task and I really felt that. I've seen parsing with ',' or ' ' but I have no idea how to deal with semicolon';'. Also, as I have to proceed calculation process with thousands lines of them, modeling 'while' structure is another consider.

Answer (score 1):

I said that C was annoying because you had to worry about buffer size when stepping through a text file line by line and also because it doesn't have a split function. It does, however, have `strtok()` which can be used to loop through the tokens you get when splitting a string at a delimiter. The following code implements a function which takes a string of semicolon-delimited doubles and reads them into a passed double array (using `atof()` to convert to a double). You also pass it a starting index (0-based) and the number, len, of doubles to grab. No real error checking is done, although it won't crash if you run out of tokens before you grab len doubles. Included is a simple driver function which hard-wired in the first line you gave above:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void get_doubles(char* line, int start, int len, double* nums);

int main(void){
    char  test_string[] = "2.01; 0.441726296835717; -0.564010125045376; -0.416244141468842; -0.559920773166141; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0;";
    int i;
    double my_nums[4];

    get_doubles(test_string, 1, 4, my_nums);
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("Number %d: %f\n",i+1,my_nums[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void get_doubles(char* line, int start, int len, double* nums){
    char* token;
    char delim[] = ";";
    int i,j;
    j = start + len;

    token = strtok(line, delim);
    for(i = 0; i < j && token != NULL; i++){
        if(start <= i){
            nums[i-start] = atof(token);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Number 1: 0.441726
Number 2: -0.564010
Number 3: -0.416244
Number 4: -0.559921
```

(By the way -- you aren't seeing a loss of precision so much as printf's default of 6 decimal places for printing doubles)

Comment: Such an amazing solution. Thank you for taking your time for me. By the way, I have another question If you do not mind...

void main()
{
 FILE *fopen(), *fp;
 double c;
 fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\imaging_tool\\inertial_data\\multi_quaternion.txt", "r");
 c = getc(fp);
 
 while (c != EOF)
 {
  
  
  putchar(c);
  c = getc(fp);

 }
 fclose(fp);
}

By doing this, I can open five sentences textfile data. I guessed it would work if I put variable 'c' instead of 'test_string[]' for reading whole data but it didn't.

Comment: I need to bring up thousands of the '`targeting data`' from text file and convert into new values by adding some formula. Reading and processing sentences one by one may be faster I guess.

Comment: 'c' in your code snippet is a single character, not a whole line. You need to loop through the file line by line using fgets. Use strtok as above to grab the data from each line. You could load it all into a large 2-dimensional array or you could process the data as it comes up. Any C book should show how to process a text file line by line. If you get stuck you can ask another question, but Stack Overflow isn't a code writing/ debugging service.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I'll try by myself along your instruction and ask again.